# Finding a span with a specific word in text using xPath

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

I have many spans with different text. But I need to find a span with a long text with a certain word inside this text.

```
<div class="commentMessage">
  <span>Any endgame spoilers</span>
</div>
```

In this case, I want to choose a span contains text with a certain word 'endgame'.

Here's what I tried:

```
//div[@class='commentMessage']/span[text()='endgame'] - but it show no results (very strange) =\
```

then I tried to find the span using all phrase:

```
//div[@class='commentMessage']/span[text()='Any endgame spoilers'] - and it works =\
```

But as I said I need to find a span using a certain word in it.

Also, I tried that construction:

```
//div[@class='commentMessage']/span[contains(text(), 'endgame')] - but Chrome xPath extension says: Type is not appropriate for the context in which the expression occurs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following xpath.

```
 //div[@class='commentMessage']/span[contains(.,'endgame')]
```

Comment: it works! thanks a lot! but can you pls explain what those dot and comma (., 'endgame') means or where can I read about it?

Comment: @YaroslavAkulov : Using dot it is checking the sub-string available or not.You can learn it from any site.check following site.https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value